# Android: how to zoom to a specific square in Skobbler maps

Tags: android, skmaps

I need to display a polyline and want to center the map on this polyline. How to zoom to a specific square consisting of two latitudes and two longitudes in Skobbler maps?

Comment: not sure, why there are two close suggestions, Why not commenting here to let me understand the reason then update my question accordingly ? :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Create an [SKBoundingBox](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.1.0/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKBoundingBox.html) from the 2 coordinates and then "fit" the visible screen to that bounding box via [fitBoundingBox](http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.1.0/com/skobbler/ngx/map/SKMapSurfaceView.html#fitBoundingBox(com.skobbler.ngx.map.SKBoundingBox,%20int,%20int))

Comment: good answer. but is there a way to center it around a polyline immediately without calculating the 2 coordinates?

Comment: Don't think so - you can zoom to a bounding box, to a track or to a route

Comment: @Ando what happen if i have 3 different coordinates or more, I've been trying to create a SKBoundingBox with more than 2 coordinates and it's been imposible. I think the correct way to calculate a boundingBox with more than 2 coordinates is extrapolating the coordinates to envelope all coordinates on a list. What do you think?

Comment: @AlexSanchez from your three (or more points) establish the most western/eastern longitude and the northern/southern latitude and those will be your four bounding box coordinates.

Comment: yeah, that's what i did @Ando, i take all points and search for most west/east longitude and north/south latitude and then combine them to find the bounding coordinates. But now a new question arise. What happen when you have some points fitted on the boundingbox but the route in between some of then is out of the bounding box, how i include those route into my BoundingBox?

Comment: If you have a route then it's best that you use zoomToRoute() - http://developer.skobbler.com/docs/android/2.3.0/com/skobbler/ngx/routing/SKRouteManager.html#zoomToRoute(float, float, int, int, int, int)

Comment: @Ando Sorry to dig out this thread, but we are facing this exact situation.
We are able to calculate the bounding boxes, etc. But, there are cases when a coordinate lies inside more than a single bounding box. For example (44.076104, 11.473820), this point falls under packages ITREG08 and ITREG18. How to decide which package to download ?

Comment: That is up to you. If you think that you need additional packages create (following custom bounding boxes), contact the Telenav team at dev@telenav.com